# Is the word good as the singular of goods correct?

Tags: grammatical-number

This question is somewhat related to inventory, and accounting.

Retail shops keep goods in warehouse. Manufacturers keep products.

Is it correct to say "give me that good", as it is "give me that product", or is there another term which is used for singular form of goods?

Comment: Anecdotally, I've never heard it used this way. 'Goods', while grammatically plural, does not seem to have a functional singular in this meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. "Goods" in that sense has no singular.

"A good" is quite rare, and used, as far as I can think, only in philosophy.

Furthermore, "goods" in the sense you mean is not normally used for specifics. It is used in general ("Sale of goods", "transport of goods") but we normally use other words when talking about the stock of a particular business; so "Give me [anything] of your goods" sounds stilted, whatever the [anything] is.

Comment: And what would be appropriate term for singular of Goods in retail?

Comment: Goods is really only used in legal language as pointed out above. It is very difficult to say what one can use, but generically, goods are also usually products. If you say retail goods, you are probably a lawyer....a retail product is the correct business term. As always these things depend on context...."resistance is futile".

Comment: I have to say that I've heard the singular usage, albeit from a charming but English-limited retailer transplanted to the US from rural Quebec...:-)

Comment: @Milan, you'll need to give us a context. I can't think of a context in which somebody would say "give me one of your X" (meaning goods, products etc), without being more specific about what they wanted. .

Comment: @Colin, imagine standing in a warehouse with your colleague and asking him to "bring you that product/thing/item/goodie..." or explain to you what is that product/thing/item/goodie. I know you can say what is this, but if you wanted to add one word after it what would it be?

Comment: @Milan, I think that's pretty unlikely, but if I did, the word would be "item".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but one can say "a goods train", for instance, whereas a usual compound does not admit a plural complementary noun. So, it would appear that there is a singular and that it is identical to the plural form.
Speaking of "goods" meaning "commercial product", if "good" were the singular of "goods" one should say "a good train" instead of "a goods train", but that would make it confusing (as meaning "the train is good"!). 
Nevertheles, the analysis of this compound example does speak for a potential singular meaning or form of "goods", which would be identical to the plural form, therefore "a goods" would mean one item. 
In fact, the Merriam Webster dictionary defines "goods" as a noun, meaning "something that has economic utility or satisfies an economic want" (definition #3) and Webster does NOT define it as a plural for that definition, as opposed to its further definitions. 
On top of that, defining "goods" as "something" makes it definitely NOT only a plural: in this way, Webster confirms my saying.

Comment: You're right that attributive nouns don't usually show plural endings, and even words that don't usually have singulars can show them in compounds ("scissor action", "trouser button").  But it's not always the case: "pants pocket" gets 10 times more hits than "pant pocket" on the iWeb corpus. In my view, neither that argument nor the argument from absence about Webster makes "goods" singular. iWeb has 5398 instances of "goods is" against 23007 of "goods are". But every instance I've looked at of "goods is" is "[singular phrase ending with goods] is", such as "The description of the goods is".